# Configuring "auth" and "credsStore" for different Docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to configure Docker for two different registries. (One ECR and docker.io) I need to configure ECR one with `ecr-login` and docker.io with simple `auth` but I'm failing to configure these at the same time. It gives the following error:

> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status
>   1, out: `not implemented`

Here is my ~/.docker/config.json

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                    "auth": "BASE64-STRING"
            }
    },
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

Why is Docker trying to use `credsStore` when `auth` is already available?

Answer (score 5):

Since docker 1.13.0 you can use the new credHelper format instead. I came here from Google having the exact same problem with credStore so thought I would add this for other to find.

Example:

```
$ cat ~/.docker/config.json 
{
        "auths": {
                "ghcr.io": {
                        "auth": "xxx"
                }
        },
        "credHelpers": {
                "xxx1.dkr.ecr.yyy.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login",
                "xxx2.dkr.ecr.yyy.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't you get errors on ecr-login.log? I have this config, but I keep getting errors of failing operation error ECR: GetAuthorizationToken.